# Calculate field Error 000539

Tags: arcgis-pro, error-000539

[image][image]I am brand new to the world of GIS and I have never used Python.

I tried running a calculate field command within the geoprocessing toolbox (not python) and I got an error.  I did a bunch of split line functions to split long lengths of sewer mains into shorter stretches. I split them manhole to manhole.  However, in the attribute table (field name - shape_Leng) the length of each split line stays the same as the original length of the longer line. But in a different field (field name - Shape.STLength()) it does update to the actual length of the split line.  I am trying to run a field calculation to make shape_Leng = Shape.STLength() but I am getting an error.

The reason I am trying to make them equal is because I am trying to integrate it with cartegraph and Cartegraph reads the length of main from the shape_Leng field, whereas I want it to read from the Shape.STLength() field which is the updated length after the split.

I am also trying to figure out how to make cartegraph read from a different field, but have not figured that out yet either.

The error I get from the geoprocessing toolbox function is:

> Parameters Input Table   arcgis.SDE.SANITARY_SEWER_MAIN Field
>   Name  Shape_Leng Expression   !Shape.STLength()! Expression
>   Type  PYTHON_9.3 Code Block    Updated Input
>   Table arcgis.SDE.SANITARY_SEWER_MAIN   Messages Start Time: Friday,
>   January 12, 2018 8:23:53 AM  ERROR 000539: Error running expression:
>   GPVARIANTOBJECT0.STLength()  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in  AttributeError: DescribeGeometry:
>   Get attribute STLength does not exist Failed to execute
>   (CalculateField). Failed at Friday, January 12, 2018 8:24:09 AM
>   (Elapsed Time: 15.18 seconds)

Comment: I am using ArcGis Pro.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the original post

Comment: And another screenshot of the error.

Comment: In your calculate field image, try the field "shape" which should give you the shape.length option in the helpers column. Also change it from Python_9.3 to Python.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. It worked and all fields updated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calculate field, use the field “shape” which should give you the shape.length option in the helpers column. Also, change it from “python_9.3” to “python”.